# Why is everyone surprised by Jack-Jack's powers?

Tags: continuity, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

During the scenes in Incredibles 2 where Bob is looking after Jack-Jack he is surprised to discover that the toddler has *powers* and, later, Helen is also surprised to discover he has powers.

But Jack-Jack's powers were very much demonstrated in the final scenes of the original Incredibles when Jack-Jack thwarts Syndrome's attempt to kidnap him by using some of them. **We** know he has powers and the family were watching while he used them.

How come Jack-Jack's powers come as a surprise to the family?

Comment: See this pretty full answer on SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191284/why-is-everyone-surprised-that-jack-jack-has-powers

Comment: Actually, look closer, they're asking 2 different things. That Q asked why they're surprised their offspring *would* have powers. This one is about continuity and asks why they're suprised if they already *saw* he has powers in the first movie.

Answer (score 7):

**They couldn't see what was going on** when Syndrome kidnapped Jack Jack.

Jack Jack starts displaying his powers when he and Syndrome are *waaay* up in the air. Here's the family's POV:

[image]

Those two blue specks there are Syndrome's jet boots. It's barely a dot to them. So they can see *something* might be happening to them both up there, but not *what*:

> **Helen:** Something's happening. What's happening?

A few other factors contribute to them missing Jack Jack's transformations:

- It's dusk, so visibility is a bit poor;
- They're directly under Syndrome and Jack Jack, so it's possible they're mainly seeing *feet*;
- They're in a state of panic and their first priority right now is "our baby is being kidnapped". For all they know, whatever weird
  things are happening up there are because *Syndrome* is doing something to *Jack Jack*.

Bob then launches Helen towards Jack Jack, but only *after* Jack Jack starts falling and is no longer transforming.